# Difference in Launch Image and Launch File

Tags: ios, xcode, image

The documentation for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus says to use a launch file instead of a launch image.  I'm having a tough time understanding exactly what a launch file is, as all I've done before on apps were the default default@2x and default-568h@2x images.  Can I no longer do .png images for the 6 and 6 plus?

Comment: Yes you can, but since this will mean that you will have a lot of images in your project you can now also use a NIB file. With the advantages of autolayout.

Comment: Thanks @rckoenes.  Do you know the naming scheme for 6 and 6 Plus launch images, if I go that route?

Comment: I'm using assets catalog where the images are just added. No idea if you can just supply them separately